# How to creat a URL from google drive that wiil contain the file name?

Tags: url, google-drive-api, google-docs

I need to create Hyperlinks to list of files that are on Google drive(8000 files...). in order to produce the list that will be the hyperlinks at GIS, the URL have to contain the file name

I need the URL will be

- https://drive.google.com/MyDomain/MyDirectorey/filename.pdf

Is it possible ? and if so how to ?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. Has never been a drive feature. At most you could write a webserver that receives such urls (starting with your url not google's) and redirect to the appropiate file.

Comment: is it possible to upload the files regularly and write a script that take there URLs ?