# Using Google Drive public files with same name as local in your web page but directory structure of google

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a project where I need to upload a bulk of pdf files on my website which are already available in my google drive. My question is:

Can I use my file names exactly the way it is displayed or uploaded on Google drive?

For example: if my filename on my local system was XYZ.pdf and I uploaded it on Google drive, Is it possible to provide a link on my website like //drive.google.com/google_directory_name/another_directory_name/XYZ.pdf so that user can download it directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to creat a URL from google drive that wiil contain the file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454342/how-to-creat-a-url-from-google-drive-that-wiil-contain-the-file-name)

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29454342/2213940 which isnt easy to find as its at -1 score.

Comment: Still matches proposed dup